# How to find the first term given the common ratio and the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The ratio of a GP is $r$ = $2$ and the sum to eight terms is $1785$. Find the first term.

I have no real idea on how to approach this problem, so far I tried:

Since the $r$ is given I tried dividing $1785$ by $2$ and then divided that answer so on and so forth by $2$ 8 times, but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What is `GP`? <char filler>

Comment: Geometric progression @Argyll

Comment: Feel free to edit that in your question. I ask because "GP" is not considered an easily understandable acronym.

Comment: @Argyll In the UK, [it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_practitioner#United_Kingdom) ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer: UK must be a wonderland of math-loving people. I need to visit some time :3

Comment: @Argyll I guess the ":3" means "yes", but I have to make sure. You did notice what the link is, didn't you?

Comment: @DanielFischer: No I didn't notice the link. I guess I am too dumb to be a mathematician. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$S_n=a_1\times\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

where $r\not=1$

$$S_8=a_1\times\frac{1-2^8}{1-2}=1785$$

$$255a_1=1785$$

$$a_1=7$$

Answer (score 0):

May help to write down the equations. The terms of the GP are:

$$ \{ a_o , a_o r , a_o r^2, a_o r^3, a_o r^4, a_o r^5 , a_o r^6 , a_o r^7 \}$$

Where $a_o$ is first term

It is said in the question that,

$$ a_o \left[ 1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + r^4 + r^5 + r^6 + r^7 \right]= 1785$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If the first term was $1$, the sum would be $255$. (Why ? How is this helpful ?)